# How to request the latest core OpenGL profile with GLFW?

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

I am new to OpenGL and GLFW, and I wanted to make a little graphics engine in Python using the GLFW Python bindings and the [moderngl](https://moderngl.readthedocs.io/en/5.8.2/) library to get an OpenGL context. From the [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_hints_ctx) of GLFW, if I leave the `glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR` and `glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` at their default values I should get the latest OpenGL context available on my system. In addition, I also want to enforce the use of a core profile so I don't get deprecated functionality by using `glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)`. However, doing that seems to force me to specify explicitly the context version, otherwise, it fails to create the window. Because of that, I am no longer able to request the latest version available. Here's my sample code:

```py
import platform
import sys

import glfw
import moderngl as mgl


def glfw_error_callback(error: int, description: bytes) -> None:
    print(f"GLFW error [{error}]: {description.decode()}", file=sys.stderr)


glfw.set_error_callback(glfw_error_callback)
if not glfw.init():
    sys.exit("Failed to initialize GLFW")

glfw.window_hint(glfw.RESIZABLE, False)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.DOUBLEBUFFER, True)
# I want to use the core profile to avoid deprecated functions,
# but doing so forces me to specify the context version,
# which means I can't get the latest version.
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6)
if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, True)

window = glfw.create_window(800, 600, "Demo window", None, None)
if not window:
    sys.exit("Failed to create GLFW window")
glfw.make_context_current(window)
glfw.swap_interval(1)

ctx = mgl.create_context()  # Create ModernGL context to see the context version

print("OpenGL info:")
print(f"  Vendor: {ctx.info['GL_VENDOR']}")
print(f"  Renderer: {ctx.info['GL_RENDERER']}")
print(f"  Version: {ctx.info['GL_VERSION']}")

while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.poll_events()

glfw.destroy_window(window)
ctx.release()
glfw.terminate()
```

I have no problem specifying a minimum version (Maybe I'll want to use features of 4.0+ in the future), but specifying these window hints gives me a context with **exactly** the version I specified and not a higher version. To me, it seems logical to request a minimum version, but allow and even support the use of higher versions if available. If I say I need a minimum of OpenGL 3.3, then I shouldn't have a problem with a context of 4.6, but it doesn't seem to be possible with my current setup.

My question is, how can I request the latest OpenGL version available and force the core profile with GLFW? Since it seems harder than it needs to be, maybe it's not how I should work? Is there a reason to request a specific version like 4.6 instead of specifying a minimum version and getting the latest version compatible with my specifications? In other words, what is the "right" way to request an OpenGL context with GLFW?

Comment: "*specifying these window hints gives me a context with exactly the version I specified and not a higher version*" How do you know that? And what OS and driver are you using? Most drivers take your request as a minimum.

Comment: @NicolBolas I printed the context version. It gave me `3.3.0 NVIDIA 546.17` when setting the hints to 3.3 and `4.6.0 NVIDIA 546.17` when setting them to 4.6. I am running on Windows 11.

Comment: And what happens if you set it to 4.3?

Comment: @NicolBolas I get `4.3.0 NVIDIA 546.17`

Answer (score 0):

Just done this in C but the same steps should work in Python.

```
minor = 8;
mainWindow = NULL;
glfwSetErrorCallback(ignoreGLFWErr);
while (mainWindow == NULL && minor > 0) {
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, minor);
    mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(512, 512, "GL Workout", NULL, NULL);
    minor -= 1;
}
if (mainWindow == NULL)
    Fail("Cannot create GLFW window with at least GL 4.1");
```

I first do all the GLFW setup except for the minor version with my standard GLFW error callback in place.
Then I have a target minor version, which I'm starting at 8 even though OpenGL 4.8 isn't out yet; and I make the GLFW error hander be a no-op.
Then just keep trying lower and lower minor versions until it works or the version gets too low.

(Not shown, after creating the window I re-install my GLFW usual error callback.)